# How to update a group of cells with new values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheets file with several 'pages' the first page has a list of items with values broken down by people and how many items they have.

i.e
Banana:
Steve : 67
Dave : 6
William : 7

and each person has their own stock page

i.e
Steve:
Banana : 67
Apple : 6
Orange : 7

on the main page i need a 'swap' function, the ability to say 10 apples have been swapped to bananas and update the value in the stock page of the right person to their new values.

I hope that makes sense, I really dont know how to explain otherwise.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share a copy of your Sheet so I can see the actual layout?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hWzykRiPqtSTO_L4NTGFXLsx_KYc2bJGLe8hzNJwH7Y/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: inputting a value in the from and to fields is the values i need to have changed on the other sheets

Comment: Post an image of the sheet and I'll take a look at it but I won't follow links to offsite resources

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you simplify the structure of the data and perhaps consolidate the tabs?

It obviously depends on your content, but a layout like this would be easy to manage and record the 'swaps':

[image]

Columns `A:G` contain static data.

`A12:G` contain the swap info. A formula in `H12` would highlight any issues where the swap values don't equal 0:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(if(C12:C+D12:D+E12:E+F12:F+G12:G=0,,"<-- Error"))`

The `QUERY` in J1 would be:

`=query({B:G},"select Col1,sum(Col2),sum(Col3),sum(Col4),sum(Col5),sum(Col6) where Col1 is not null and not Col1 contains 'Item' group by Col1 label sum(Col2) 'Banana', sum(Col3) 'Apple', sum(Col4) 'Orange', sum(Col5) 'Strawberry', sum(Col6) 'Raddish' ",1)`

I can explain this further if needed, with a breakdown.

Even if you want to keep the separate sheets for each person, this sheet in the screengrab could be where the data is consolidated, then pushed back to separate sheets. You have got colour on the people sheets from `E2:F30` so I suspect you may want to enhance what I'm suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

I'm agree with @Aresvik. The task doesn't even need any scripts. It can and should be done via formulas.

Nevertheless just for fun I've made the function `processData()` which does the work:

```
function processData() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  

  // create customers object
  // customers.name.fruit : number
  // it gets list of customers and number of fruits from customers sheets 
  // but it's not necessary,
  // everything can be obtained from 'Totals' sheet (columns 'B' and 'C') as well

  const customers = {};

  class Customer {
    constructor(name) {
      const fruits = ss.getSheetByName(name).getRange("B3:C30").getValues();
      fruits.map( f => this[f[0]] = f[1] );
      delete this[""];
    }
  }

  const customers_list = ss.getSheets().slice(1,).map(s => s.getName());
  customers_list.map(c => customers[c] = new Customer(c));
  

  // START ---------------------------------------

  // process 'Totals' sheet

  const totals = ss.getSheets()[0];
  
  var range = totals.getRange("B3:H10"); // banana
  calculate_range(range);
  
  range = range.offset(14,0); // apple, +14 rows
  calculate_range(range);
  
  range = range.offset(15,0); // orange, +15 rows <-- your bad
  calculate_range(range);
  
  range = range.offset(14,0); // strawberry, +14 rows
  calculate_range(range);
  
  range = range.offset(14,0); // raddish, +14 rows
  calculate_range(range);


  // update customers sheets

  update_customers_sheets(customers);


  // alert message

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Done");


  // END ------------------------------------------



  // a couple inner functions    

  function calculate_range(range) {
    var data = range.getValues();
    var fruit = data[0][0];

    for (var row=1; row<data.length; row++) {
      var customer_name  = data[row][0];
      data[row][1] = customers[customer_name][fruit] + data[row][6] - data[row][5];
      customers[customer_name][fruit] = data[row][1];
      data[row][5] = 0;
      data[row][6] = 0;
    }

    range.setValues(data);
  }
  

  function update_customers_sheets(customers) {

    for (var c in customers) {
      var range = ss.getSheetByName(c).getRange("B3:C7");
      var data = range.getValues();
      for (var row=0; row<data.length; row++) {
        let fruit = data[row][0];
        data[row][1] = customers[c][fruit];
      }
      range.setValues(data);
    }

  }

}
```

You can add the function in your custom menu 'Script Center Menu' if you change the function `onOpen()` this way:

```
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [
    {
      name : "Process Data",
      functionName: "processData"
    }
  ];
  sheet.addMenu("Script Center Menu", entries);
};
```

Comment: Impressive scripts!